# What does "Supports python 3" mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x

On a developer site like PyPI, when a module says it supports Python 3 (like the [`requests` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/2.5.0)), can I use it with any Python 3 release or is it literally Python 3.0?

If it does mean the latest Python version, how can you be sure that it is true? For example if the project has been untouched for like 1 or 2 years?

Comment: Although the question is not closely related to programming as in producing code, and it should be posted in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ or something like that, generally I don't see why it is downvoted, it is a legitimate question,.

Comment: I am not sure how to clarify this question further, since someone obviously knew what I was asking directly and answered.

Comment: It is a bad practice to down vote and not leave a comment as to why. No  actual contribution to the quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supporting Python 3 means supporting Python 3 up to the current point release.

Python point releases are *backward compatible*. What works on 3.0 should generally work on 3.4. See [PEP 387](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0387/) for the general guidelines on this policy. Python 3.4 added some [deprecations](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#deprecations-in-the-python-api) but none of these will affect packages that were once only written for 3.0, at least until Python 3.5 or 3.6 are released.

Exceptions are more easily made for C extensions. Python 3.3 saw a [new internal Unicode format](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-393-flexible-string-representation), but support for the old Unicode C APIs is still present in 3.4.

The 3.4 deprecations are for the most part for code that has been *extremely rarely* used, if at all. Any code that uses features that are now slated for removal should trigger warning messages.

For future Python 3.x releases, just download the package and use it. If anything were to break, look through the *Deprecated* entries in recent [Python 3 release notes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/) to see if the project may have been using a feature since removed.

In any case, try and check the project documentation; a good project will list exact versions on which they have tested the package. The [`requests` project](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) states:

> Requests officially supports Python 2.7 & 3.4–3.7, and runs great on PyPy.

Comment: Not the downvoter, But do Include a line about the OPs second para too.

Comment: @BhargavRao: That does address the second paragraph too. They can be sure because Python 3 hasn't removed anything that has been deprecated anything *yet*, all 3.x releases are fully backwards compatible.

Comment: I don't get the downvoters, this is a good answer. +1

Comment: Your answer is on point, thank you!

Comment: I think [this](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0352/#retracted-ideas) is an exception ;-) to what you're saying about 3.x always being backward compatible with 3.0. Also, personally I'd be somewhat reluctant about just downloading the package and seeing what breaks.

Comment: @martineau: The idea there still isn't implemented. Such deprecations are done very gradually, and only 3.4 has introduced deprecations so far.

Comment: Well, they actually didn't remove the `message` attribute on `BaseException` in 2.7, and may have left in until 3.4.0, because it's removal in release broke part of one of my answers that previously had worked in both 2.7.x and some earlier 3.x that still had it. The attribute's removal isn't mentioned in the _What’s New In Python 3.4_.

Comment: @martineau: ah, but BaseException.message was never documented.